# Spring boot failing to start rest service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I tried to simulate the RESTful Web Service from the spring home page "https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/". I am able to get the expected output for the given example, so i did a little enhancement i.e tried to fetch some count from the oracle database and display as part of response but it didn't work.

Maven compilation works fine but when i run the spring boot i am getting the below error, i don't know what could be the reason. I am new to spring, can someone help me?

My configuration details are
Mac 10.9
EclipseLuna 4.4.1
Java-8
maven3.2.1
spring 3.6

**Spring Boot Error:**

```
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.2.RELEASE)

        2015-03-11 18:36:25.862  INFO 7298 --- [           main] 

com.test.Application                     : Starting Application on LM-MAA-00668611 with PID 7298 (/Users/sijayaraman/Documents/workspace/luna/CopyofSpringRest/target/classes started by sijayaraman in /Users/sijayaraman/Documents/workspace/luna/CopyofSpringRest)
    2015-03-11 18:36:25.900  INFO 7298 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5427c60c: startup date [Wed Mar 11 18:36:25 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    2015-03-11 18:36:26.366  INFO 7298 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
    2015-03-11 18:36:26.405  INFO 7298 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Users/sijayaraman/Documents/workspace/luna/CopyofSpringRest/target/classes/, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.10/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.10/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.10/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.10.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.10/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.2/logback-core-1.1.2.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.20/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.20/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.20.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.20/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.20.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.20/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.20.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.5/jackson-databind-2.4.5.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.5/jackson-annotations-2.4.5.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.5/jackson-core-2.4.5.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sijayaraman/.m2/maven.repo/com/oracle/ojdbc5/11.2.0.1.0/ojdbc5-11.2.0.1.0.jar]
    2015-03-11 18:36:26.411 ERROR 7298 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration#transactionManager due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:51)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:124)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:318)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
        at com.test.Application.main(Application.java:11)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1962)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:490)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:534)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:677)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:621)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:968)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:257)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:246)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:227)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:158)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:119)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:83)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.aop.Advice
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 36 common frames omitted

    2015-03-11 18:36:26.422  INFO 7298 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5427c60c: startup date [Wed Mar 11 18:36:25 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    2015-03-11 18:36:26.424  WARN 7298 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5427c60c: startup date [Wed Mar 11 18:36:25 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:150)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
        at com.test.Application.main(Application.java:11)

    2015-03-11 18:36:26.424  WARN 7298 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
```

**Application.java**

```
   package com.test;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
```

**Employee.java**

```
package com.test;

public class Employee {

    private final int count;
    private final String name;

    public Employee(int count,String name) {
        this.count = count;
        this.name = name;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeController.java**

```
package com.test;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDao dao;

    @RequestMapping("/employee")
    public Employee employee(@RequestParam(value="name") String name) {

        System.out.println("Count="+dao.getTotalCount());
        return new Employee(dao.getTotalCount(),name);
    }

}
```

**EmployeeDao.java**

```
package com.test;

public interface EmployeeDao {
    public int getTotalCount();

}
```

**EmployeeDaoImpl.java**

```
 package com.test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao{

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {  
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;  
    } 

    public int getTotalCount(){
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int numOfTrades = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt("select count(*) from employee");
        return numOfTrades;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@testserver.com:2126:QADBA9FU
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=password123
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
           <artifactId>ojdbc5</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using spring-boot, add the dependency below in order to use autoconfiguration

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In your application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@testserver.com:2126:QADBA9FU
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=password123
```

**EDIT 1**

Remove this in yout EmployeeController

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/Users/sijayaraman/Documents/workspace/luna/CopyofSpringRest/sbeans.xml");
EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDaoImpl)ctx.getBean("employeedao");
```

instead use

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeDao dao;
```

Also, annotate class

```
@Component
public class EmployeeDaoImpl ...
```

**EDIT 02**

Download the ojdbc6.jar from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html and install in your maven local repository

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile={Path/to/your/ojdbc.jar} -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then change your oracle dependency by

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Also, annotate `EmployeeDaoImpl` as a `@Repository` to get `JdbcTemplate` injected. And delete `sbeans.xml` ... and whatever is trying to load it.

Comment: And delete the `spring-jdbc` import from `pom.xml`.

Comment: JdbcTemplate must have @Autowired

Comment: load application Context from the xml is not needed. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @EddúMeléndez, thanks for looking into this issue. I modified as per your suggestion but same problem exists, i am always getting this error  "Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration#transactionManager"  error.  I have updated the suggested code in the original post also. Can you please recheck it?

Comment: @Steve and Eddu, if anyone of you solve this issue,  i will give 50 bounty for the right answer. I am ok with mysql db also.

Comment: Remove: `dao= new EmployeeDaoImpl();` from the controller.

Comment: Also looks like `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` hasn't been added to the `pom.xml` yet.

Comment: Autowired annotation inject the class instance in the field. For that reason you don't need to instantiate the class.

Comment: i have already "spring-boot-starter-jdbc" in my pom and also i removed  dao= new EmployeeDaoImpl(); but the same problem exists.

Comment: Can you share your project in github, please?

Comment: I have reviewed your configuration and everything is working fine with a embedded database. So, I think that the error is with oracle. Check my EDIT 2 section please.

Comment: Instead of pom, i manually downloaded the  ojdbc6 jar and set it in the classpath and its worked. thanks for you help. As i promised i will give you 50 Bounty  asap. Bounty for this question is not yet opened, so i will give you once its opened. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I am not able to see bounty button at this moment. I going  to unaccept the answer and see the button is enabled,  if so i will provide the bounty and accept the answer.

Comment: Bounty will be enabled after 12 hours , so please wait.

Comment: i awarded bounty for this answer, it will be credited in 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the root of your problem, but you are not accessing your dao correctly. The main principle of Spring is Dependency Injection, which means `Controller` should not be getting it's DAO. Instead it should be either autowired or set in the config file.

Then you `Controller` would look like this:

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {
     @Autowired
     EmployeeDao dao;

    @RequestMapping("/employee")
    public Employee employee(@RequestParam(value="name") String name) {

        System.out.println("Count="+dao.getTotalCount());
        return new Employee(dao.getTotalCount(),name);
    }

}
```

You will need to add the `sbeans.xml` to the configuration. Try adding 
`@ImportXml("classpath:sbeans.xml")` to `Application.java` :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportXml("classpath:sbeans.xml") 
public class Application
```

or better yet rewrite `sbeans.xml` in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting -

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice

So fix this first with -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```